# All Common Substrings Between Two Strings

Tags: c#

I am working on C# to find all the common substrings between two strings. For instance, if the input is: 
S1= "need asssitance with email"
S2= "email assistance needed"

The output should be- 'need assistance email'

The below code returns the longest common substring, but I want my code to return all the common substrings.  Any help is much appreciated!

```
static void commonsubstrings()
    {
        input1 = "need asssitance with email";
        input2 = "email assistance needed"

        if (input2.Length > input1.Length)
        {
            swap = input1;
            input1 = input2;
            input2 = swap;
        }

        int k = 1;
        String temp;
        String longTemp = "";
        for (int i = 0; (i <= input1.Length); i++)
        {
            if ((i == input1.Length))
            {
                if (longest != null)
                {
                    k = longest.Length + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    k = 1;
                }
                temp = input1.Substring(1, input1.Length - 1);
                if (temp.Equals(""))
                {
                    break;
                }
                if (k <= temp.Length)
                {
                    i = k - 1;
                    input1 = temp;
                    if ((longest != null) && (longest.Length > longTemp.Length))
                    {
                        longTemp = longest;
                    }
                }
            }
            holder1 = input1.Substring(0, k);

            for (int j = 0; (j < input2.Length) && (j + k <= input2.Length); j++)
            {
                check1 = input2.Substring(j, k);
                if (holder1.Equals(check1))
                {
                    longest = holder1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            k++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(longest);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

}

Comment: Does the result have to be in any order?

Comment: All common substrings?  Single characters?  Is "Ema" and "Emai" and "Email" three different matching substrings?

Comment: Did you mean to have too many "s" characters in input1? Is that part of the question or a typo? Are you trying to say that "asssistance" and "assistance" are common?

Comment: How do you go from all substrings to the desired output, "need assistance email"?

Comment: Might be worth investigating diff-match-patch http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/ we have used it for this function with great success.

Comment: From the example provided, it looks like this is all common words, not all common substrings. If that's the case, I'd split both strings into arrays of words and just do nested for loops to compare arrays.

Comment: Moe- the order of the result does not matter. I just needed to know the common sub-strings between two strings. I have to group the strings later on the basis of matched substrings. The solution you gave worked perfectly for my case. Thank you very much for quick responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    public static string [] CommonString(string left, string right)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        string [] rightArray = right.Split();
        string [] leftArray = left.Split();

        result.AddRange(rightArray.Where(r => leftArray.Any(l => l.StartsWith(r))));

        // must check other way in case left array contains smaller words than right array
        result.AddRange(leftArray.Where(l => rightArray.Any(r => r.StartsWith(l))));

        return result.Distinct().ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Instead of text.Split(' ') I would use text.Split(). Then you also include other white-space characters as tab or newline.-

Answer (score 5):

A different approach: you could use [levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to find the similarity of two words. If the distance is less than a specified value you could consider two strings as equal. Then you can use the levenshtein comparer for `Enumerable.Intersect`.

Then it's simple as:

```
string S1= "need asssitance with email" ;
string S2 = "email assistance needed";
string[] words1 = S1.Split();
string[] words2 = S2.Split();
var wordsIntersecting = words1.Intersect(words2, new LevenshteinComparer());
string output = string.Join(" ", wordsIntersecting);
```

output: `need asssitance email`

Here is the custom comparer:

```
class LevenshteinComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public int MaxDistance { get; set; }
    private Levenshtein _Levenshtein = new Levenshtein();

    public LevenshteinComparer() : this(50) { }

    public LevenshteinComparer(int maxDistance)
    {
        this.MaxDistance = maxDistance;
    }

    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        int distance = _Levenshtein.iLD(x, y);
        return distance <= MaxDistance;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return 0; 
    }
}
```

and here is an implementation of the levenshtein algoritm:

```
public class Levenshtein
{
    ///*****************************
    /// Compute Levenshtein distance 
    /// Memory efficient version
    ///*****************************
    public int iLD(String sRow, String sCol)
    {
        int RowLen = sRow.Length;  // length of sRow
        int ColLen = sCol.Length;  // length of sCol
        int RowIdx;                // iterates through sRow
        int ColIdx;                // iterates through sCol
        char Row_i;                // ith character of sRow
        char Col_j;                // jth character of sCol
        int cost;                   // cost

        /// Test string length
        if (Math.Max(sRow.Length, sCol.Length) > Math.Pow(2, 31))
            throw (new Exception("\nMaximum string length in Levenshtein.iLD is " + Math.Pow(2, 31) + ".\nYours is " + Math.Max(sRow.Length, sCol.Length) + "."));

        // Step 1

        if (RowLen == 0)
        {
            return ColLen;
        }

        if (ColLen == 0)
        {
            return RowLen;
        }

        /// Create the two vectors
        int[] v0 = new int[RowLen + 1];
        int[] v1 = new int[RowLen + 1];
        int[] vTmp;



        /// Step 2
        /// Initialize the first vector
        for (RowIdx = 1; RowIdx <= RowLen; RowIdx++)
        {
            v0[RowIdx] = RowIdx;
        }

        // Step 3

        /// Fore each column
        for (ColIdx = 1; ColIdx <= ColLen; ColIdx++)
        {
            /// Set the 0'th element to the column number
            v1[0] = ColIdx;

            Col_j = sCol[ColIdx - 1];


            // Step 4

            /// Fore each row
            for (RowIdx = 1; RowIdx <= RowLen; RowIdx++)
            {
                Row_i = sRow[RowIdx - 1];


                // Step 5

                if (Row_i == Col_j)
                {
                    cost = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    cost = 1;
                }

                // Step 6

                /// Find minimum
                int m_min = v0[RowIdx] + 1;
                int b = v1[RowIdx - 1] + 1;
                int c = v0[RowIdx - 1] + cost;

                if (b < m_min)
                {
                    m_min = b;
                }
                if (c < m_min)
                {
                    m_min = c;
                }

                v1[RowIdx] = m_min;
            }

            /// Swap the vectors
            vTmp = v0;
            v0 = v1;
            v1 = vTmp;

        }


        // Step 7

        /// Value between 0 - 100
        /// 0==perfect match 100==totaly different
        /// 
        /// The vectors where swaped one last time at the end of the last loop,
        /// that is why the result is now in v0 rather than in v1
        //System.Console.WriteLine("iDist=" + v0[RowLen]);
        int max = System.Math.Max(RowLen, ColLen);
        return ((100 * v0[RowLen]) / max);
    }





    ///*****************************
    /// Compute the min
    ///*****************************

    private int Minimum(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        int mi = a;

        if (b < mi)
        {
            mi = b;
        }
        if (c < mi)
        {
            mi = c;
        }

        return mi;
    }

    ///*****************************
    /// Compute Levenshtein distance         
    ///*****************************

    public int LD(String sNew, String sOld)
    {
        int[,] matrix;              // matrix
        int sNewLen = sNew.Length;  // length of sNew
        int sOldLen = sOld.Length;  // length of sOld
        int sNewIdx; // iterates through sNew
        int sOldIdx; // iterates through sOld
        char sNew_i; // ith character of sNew
        char sOld_j; // jth character of sOld
        int cost; // cost

        /// Test string length
        if (Math.Max(sNew.Length, sOld.Length) > Math.Pow(2, 31))
            throw (new Exception("\nMaximum string length in Levenshtein.LD is " + Math.Pow(2, 31) + ".\nYours is " + Math.Max(sNew.Length, sOld.Length) + "."));

        // Step 1

        if (sNewLen == 0)
        {
            return sOldLen;
        }

        if (sOldLen == 0)
        {
            return sNewLen;
        }

        matrix = new int[sNewLen + 1, sOldLen + 1];

        // Step 2

        for (sNewIdx = 0; sNewIdx <= sNewLen; sNewIdx++)
        {
            matrix[sNewIdx, 0] = sNewIdx;
        }

        for (sOldIdx = 0; sOldIdx <= sOldLen; sOldIdx++)
        {
            matrix[0, sOldIdx] = sOldIdx;
        }

        // Step 3

        for (sNewIdx = 1; sNewIdx <= sNewLen; sNewIdx++)
        {
            sNew_i = sNew[sNewIdx - 1];

            // Step 4

            for (sOldIdx = 1; sOldIdx <= sOldLen; sOldIdx++)
            {
                sOld_j = sOld[sOldIdx - 1];

                // Step 5

                if (sNew_i == sOld_j)
                {
                    cost = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    cost = 1;
                }

                // Step 6

                matrix[sNewIdx, sOldIdx] = Minimum(matrix[sNewIdx - 1, sOldIdx] + 1, matrix[sNewIdx, sOldIdx - 1] + 1, matrix[sNewIdx - 1, sOldIdx - 1] + cost);

            }
        }

        // Step 7

        /// Value between 0 - 100
        /// 0==perfect match 100==totaly different
        System.Console.WriteLine("Dist=" + matrix[sNewLen, sOldLen]);
        int max = System.Math.Max(sNewLen, sOldLen);
        return (100 * matrix[sNewLen, sOldLen]) / max;
    }
}
```

Credits to the Levenshtein class to: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13525/Fast-memory-efficient-Levenshtein-algorithm

Comment: Tim- I have tried levenshtein algoritm earlier, but somehow it did not return the expected response. For instance, if I have two strings S1= "general question about annotation" and S2= "create annotation with callout so that the point features is not needed". The common word here is "annotation" but the result I am getting is "about annotation". I'm not sure why.

Comment: As I've mentioned my approach is comparing words by similarity. So I'm first splitting both texts by white-space characters. Maybe you have used a different approach. Note that above code is complete and gives the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

**Use Set-Intersections**

Start with a routine to find all possible substrings of a string.  Here it is in Python, it's an 'exercise for the reader' to translate it to C#':

```
def allSubstr(instring):
  retset = set()
  retset.add(instring)
  totlen = len(instring)
  for thislen in range(0, totlen):
    for startpos in range(0, totlen):
      # print "startpos: %s, thislen: %s" % (startpos, thislen)
      addStr = instring[startpos:startpos+thislen]
      # print "addstr: %s" % (addStr)
      retset.add(addStr)
  print "retset total: %s" % (retset)
  return retset

set1 = allSubstr('abcdefg')
set2 = allSubstr('cdef')
print set1.intersection(set2)
```

Here's the output:

```
>>> set1 = allSubstr('abcdefg')
retset total: set(['', 'cde', 'ab', 'ef', 'cd', 'abcdef', 'abc', 'efg', 'bcde', 'cdefg', 'bc', 'de',   'bcdef', 'abcd', 'defg', 'fg', 'cdef', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'g', 'f', 'bcd', 'abcde', 'abcdefg', 'bcdefg', 'def'])
>>> set2 = allSubstr('cdef')
retset total: set(['', 'cde', 'c', 'ef', 'e', 'd', 'f', 'de', 'cd', 'cdef', 'def'])
>>> 
>>> set1.intersection(set2)
set(['', 'cde', 'c', 'de', 'e', 'd', 'f', 'ef', 'cd', 'cdef', 'def'])
```

No, you're not interested in subsets of length 1.  But, you can always add a limit to length before you do the set.add() call.

Comment: Is breaking both down really necessary? I would think that you could break down one, sort longest-first, then do a contains and discard any not contained in the other. That doesn't account for "email" containing "em" and "il", which could be done by a second dedup step within the match set, but it should handle the basic question, no?