# How to find biggest substring from string1 into string2

Tags: c#, arrays, string, string-matching

Lets suppose i have two strings `string1` and `string2`.

`var string1 = "images of canadian geese goslings";`

`var string2 = "Canadian geese with goslings pictures to choose from, with no signup needed";`

I need to find biggest substring of `string1` which matches in `string2`.

here biggest substring will be  `"canadian geese"` which is matching in `string2`.

How can I find it? I tried breaking `string1` into `char[]` and find words then merged matched words but that failed my objective.

Comment: The naive approach would be to get all subtrings of string1 in descending length (ie all substrings of length n, then all substrings of length n-1, n-2) and check if they are a substring of string2. The first match you find, is the longest substring of both, although there may be others of the same length.

Comment: @Sinatr Probably the downvotes are for the missing of any code and own effort

Comment: One possible solution is to [find all substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17054989/1997232) and then take the longest.

Comment: There is pretty similar question [C# find the length of the longest substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079458/c-sharp-find-the-length-of-the-longest-substring), this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45079724/4728685) seems to be a good option

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski The answer you referenced just searches for the longest token in a string separated by a certain separator (for instance the longest word in a sentence)

Comment: You are searching for whole words only? "Biggest substring" in terms of number of characters or number of whole words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following code https://dotnetfiddle.net/aPyw3o

```
public class Program {

static IEnumerable<string> substrings(string s, int length) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i + length <= s.Length; i++) {
        var ss = s.Substring(i, length);
        if (!(ss.StartsWith(" ") || ss.EndsWith(" ")))
            yield return ss;
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    int count = 0;
    var string1 = "images of canadian geese goslings";
    var string2 = "Canadian geese with goslings pictures to choose from, with no signup needed";
    string result = null;
    for (int i = string1.Length; i>0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(result); i--) {
        foreach (string s in substrings(string1, i)) {
            count++;
            if (string2.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0) {
                result = s;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) 
        Console.WriteLine("no common substrings found");
    else 
        Console.WriteLine("'" + result + "'");
    Console.WriteLine(count);
}

}
```

The `substrings` method returns all substrings of the string `s` with the length of `length` (for the `yield` have a look at the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) We skip substrings that start or end with a space, as we don't want whitespaces to make a substring longer than it really is)

The outer loop iterates through all the possible length values for the substrings, from the longest (ie `string1.Length`) to the shortest (ie `1`). Then for each of the found substrings of length `i` is checked, if it's also a substring of `string2`. If that's the case, we can stop, as there cannot be any longer common substring, because we checked all longer substrings in previous iterations. But of course there may be other common substrings with length `i`

Answer (score 4):

classy loop approach - the result includes te space after geese `"canadian geese "`

```
var string1 = "images of canadian geese goslings";
var string2 = "Canadian geese with goslings pictures to choose from, with no signup needed";

string result = "";

for (int i = 0; i < string1.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < string1.Length - i; j++)
    {
        //add .Trim() here if you want to ignore space characters
        string searchpattern = string1.Substring(i, j);
        if (string2.IndexOf(searchpattern,  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1 && searchpattern.Length > result.Length)
        {
            result = searchpattern;
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/q3rHjI

**Side note:**
`canadian` and `Canadian` are not equal so you have to use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` if you want to search case insensitive

Comment: As all the comments for this answer vanished, I will share my thoughts again: This approach will work, but it is very inefficent. For mutliple reasons *1)* It starts with the shortest possible substring (ie single characters) and works it's way up to the longest. For instance *canadian* is checked before *canadian geese*. If the algorithm started with the longest possible match and then shorted the candidates, it could stop on the first match.

Comment: *2)* It checks substrings, which can never be a match, because a shorter substring starting at the same index was no match. For instance *im* is not contained in string2, therefore there is no need to check *ima*  or any longer substring of string1 starting at index 0.

Comment: *3)* It checks possible candidates, even if there is already a longer match found. If *canadian geese* is already found as a match, any candidate which is shorter than 13 characters can never be the longest common substring, thus, there is no need to search for it in string2

Comment: @derpirscher imo: readability / mainainability > performance in this case.

Comment: Yes, that's a valid point of view. My comments aren't meant as an attack, but just to give you some hints, on how you could improve your algorithm. And all my points are very simple improvements, which don't have much effect on maintainability, but a huge impact on performance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to add one more, using span/readonlymemory so you can avoid allocating all the strings that the current answers create. Note I didn't do any check for starting space or ending space as that does not seem to be a requirement for the question. This does do a case insensitive search, if you don't want that you can make it more efficient by using the built in indexof and dropping the case insensitive compares.

```
    static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        var string1 = "images of canadian geese goslings";

        var string2 = "Canadian geese with goslings pictures to choose from, with no signup needed";

        var longest = FindLongestMatchingSubstring(string1, string2);

        Console.WriteLine(longest);
    }

    static string FindLongestMatchingSubstring(string lhs, string rhs)
    {
        var left = lhs.AsMemory();
        var right = rhs.AsMemory();

        ReadOnlyMemory<char> longest = ReadOnlyMemory<char>.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < left.Length; ++i)
        {
            foreach (var block in FindMatchingSubSpans(left, i, right))
            {
                if (block.Length > longest.Length)
                    longest = block;
            }
        }

        if (longest.IsEmpty)
            return string.Empty;

        return longest.ToString();
    }

    static IEnumerable<ReadOnlyMemory<char>> FindMatchingSubSpans(ReadOnlyMemory<char> source, int pos, ReadOnlyMemory<char> matchFrom)
    {
        int lastMatch = 0;

        for (int i = pos; i < source.Length; ++i)
        {
            var ch = source.Span[i];

            int match = IndexOfChar(matchFrom, lastMatch, ch);

            if (-1 != match)
            {
                lastMatch = match + 1;

                int end = i;

                while (++end < source.Length && ++match < matchFrom.Length)
                {
                    char lhs = source.Span[end];
                    char rhs = matchFrom.Span[match];

                    if (lhs != rhs && lhs != (char.IsUpper(rhs) ? char.ToLower(rhs) : char.ToUpper(rhs)))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                yield return source.Slice(i, end - i);
            }
        }
    }

    static int IndexOfChar(ReadOnlyMemory<char> source, int pos, char ch)
    {
        char alt = char.IsUpper(ch) ? char.ToLower(ch) : char.ToUpper(ch);

        for (int i = pos; i < source.Length; ++i)
        {
            char m = source.Span[i];

            if (m == ch || m == alt)
                return i;
        }

        return -1;
    }
```